# Initiation of an object inside another

Tags: javascript, object, canvas, dom-events

I have a piece of js software that is structured like so:

```
obj = new object[id]();

function wrapperFunction (e) {
    var pos = findPos(this);
    e._x = e.pageX - pos.x;
    e._y = e.pageY - pos.y;

    var func = obj[e.type];
    if (func) {
        func(e);            
    }
}
```

__

```
obj.line = function () {    
    this.started = false;
    this.mousedown = function (e) {

    }

    this.mousemove = function (e) {
        if (this.started) {

        }
    }

    this.mouseup = function (e) {
        if (this.started) {

        }
    }
}
```

The above code block is duplicated for multiple shapes so there is also a `obj.square obj.circle` etc...

I also have a shape object that is as follows.

```
function Shape (type, color, height, width, radius, x, y) {
    this.type = type;
    this.color = color;
    this.h = height;
    this.w = width; 
    this.r = radius;
    this.points = ["x","y"];
    this.points["x"] = [x];
    this.points["y"] = [y];
};
```

I would like to initiate the shape object on a `mousedown` for each obj.* and populate the shape object with the propper info.

Now for the issue.

The `radius` is calcuated on every `mousemove` as well as `height` and `width` but when I add `shapes = new Shape(circle, black, 10, 10, null, e._x, e._y)` to the `mousemove` so it looks like...

```
this.mousemove = function (e) {
    if (this.started) {
        shapes = new Shape(circle, black, 10, 10, null, e._x, e._y);
    }
}
```

The shape object does not create.

If I create the shape object inside the wrapper function instead of the `mousemove` then the object initiates but I cannot use `radius` or `height/width`.
How can I create an object inside another object inside a wrapper function so I can use calculated terms inside the created object? Is there an alternate route to take besides what I am doing?

Comment: Where's the code that calls the above?

Comment: Are you using a JavaScript library of some sort? `obj = new object[this.id]();` is not valid vanilla JS - and is just plain wonky anyway.

Comment: @Mattyeah I am using jQuery Sorry if I trunicated my code to much I didn't want to paste everything. I figured it would be a pain to read. this.id is a var created elsewhere assume it matches line, circle, square.

Comment: @Box9 what? The code that calls the wrapper function is a jQuery on page load.

Comment: I mean what is `obj.line`? How is it being created? How is the `mousemove` event being triggered because I don't see it being attached to any DOM events? There really isn't enough info here to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from wonkiness in the `obj = new object[this.id]();` line, I *think* you're just missing a `this` keyword:

```
this.mousemove = function (e) {
    if (this.started) {
        this.shapes = new Shape(circle, black, 10, 10, null, e._x, e._y);
    }
}
```

***Edit*** just noticed more wonkiness in your code (yes, that's a technical term :). I think you want to change these lines in the constructor:

```
this.points = ["x","y"]; // creates an array, which is indexed by numbers
this.points["x"] = [x];  // tacks on some ad-hoc properties to the array, which
this.points["y"] = [y];  // doesn't really make sense
```

to this:

```
this.points = {x: x,   // I think this is what you actually mean to do.
               y: y};
```

Comment: Just tried it and that does not work, also after your edit. The object still does not create when I have a `mousedown` event

Comment: Ok, I really don't understand what you're trying to do, and how the code you've shown us fits into the bigger picture. I'll delete this answer in a bit, but could you show us a demo (such as [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of the code that works, and one of the code that doesn't work?

Comment: Thanks to what you put and me starting to put stuff in jquery I got the answer.  Thanks

Comment: Would you mind editing your question, or posting your own answer, to show us how you fixed the problem?